# Getting error pulling source

Tags: salesforcedx

I recently created a new scratch org from an existing package, and made some changes (none related to products or price books, etc.) but when I try to pull my changes I'm getting the following error when I run `sfdx force:source:pull -f`:

> ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'ListView' named 'PricebookEntry.Standard Price Book1613356242265' cannot be found

I've been trying to find what this is even referring to but nothing has been turned up. I really need to pull my changes from my scratch org but this is preventing me from doing so.

There's nothing listed in my objects folder relating to price books:

[image]

Nor are there any layouts relating to the price book objects:

[image]

How do I find and delete this or ignore this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a bug in the Source Tracking on server!

Search for the record in the `SourceMember` object by querying the record! Note this is a tooling object so in developer console you need to use tooling query

Check the screenshot below to make sure you use tooling api for query

[image]

Delete the entry where it is of type list view and has the name as error!

Next step is to wipe of the source tracking on the local by deleting the `.sfdx` folder and then run  `source pull`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. _"Search for the record in the SourceMember object by querying the record!"_ - can you elaborate on how to do this? I tried to run a query via "Query Editor" and it failed stating _"sObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported."_ - presumably I need to do something to enable queries to access the tooling object?

Comment: On my phone but check the checkbox in the query editor for tooling api

Comment: I've no idea how I missed that right next to the "Execute" button. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Were you able to retrieve eveything off once you got rid of that entry?

Comment: Yep. It all went perfectly after I followed your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Clear source tracking information with `force:source:tracking:clear` or `force:source:tracking:reset`

If source tracking gets confused, and starts reporting inaccuracies, you can clear local source tracking information with force:source:tracking:clear or both local and remote source tracking information with `force:source:tracking:reset`. Be very careful when using these commands, because they cannot be undone, and they reset source tracking at the org-level, which means other developers also have their source tracking reset.